# Make all but 1 element float left FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

I've got all my `FlowLayout` elements set to float left:

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

but I want the one on the end (right hand side) to float to the right, how can I make all but one float left?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FlowLayout doesn't support that feature.

You can use a `horizontal BoxLayout` and add `glue` before the last component. See the section on `Using Invisible Components` from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information.

One problem with the BoxLayout is that is doesn't automatically leave a space between components so you would also need to add a `Box.createHorizontalStrut(...)` for each space.

Or another option is to create a second panel that uses a BorderLayout. Then you would add your panel with the flowLayout to the LINE_START and then add the last component to the LINE_END. You would probably also need to add an EmptyBorder to this component to provide proper spacing.